# Is this a correct way to solve contact?

Tags: physics-engine

[image: logic flow]

Hi there, 
I'm learning the impulse based physics engine these days. Can someone please check my image about solving a contact( a sphere resting on ground) , and please let me know where is wrong.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a game development question.

Comment: I disagree, this is about resolving a collision found during a physics simulation, which is very much about game development.

Comment: After solving, the movement of the surface of the disc *at the point of contact with the ground* should be zero. That consists of both an angular and linear component. Here you've considered the linear component in isolation first, and applied a linear impulse to bring it to zero, then considered the angular movement separately. It looks like instead, you'd want to consider both the linear and angular effects of the impulse together, so that the *net* result is zero motion at that point (ie. linear motion taking it forward, angular motion taking it backward)

Comment: @DMGregory That will produce a perfectly elastic collision with infinite friction. Not very realistic, but the simplest model that causes a rotation velocity change.

Comment: @MooseBoys yes, exactly. The infinite friction assumption is already explicitly present in OP's version, just implemented in a way that initially halts velocity outright.

Comment: @DMGregory, thank you! After some more research today, I think I understood now. You are right. So I need to find out another way to solve the linear and angular effects simultaneously.

Comment: I just want to point out its a sad day when someone has the power to vote to close, and they vote to close physics sim questions as off topic for gamedev. "Experts answering your questions" my foot :p. Someone else upvoted that comment as well!

Comment: @AlanWolfe I don't think it's sad. This is a collaboratively edited site, so what's on-topic is a constant negotiation among the community. I've placed close votes that turned out not to match community consensus too - it happens, and we learn. A vote to close isn't an insult or condemnation, just an opinion eg. "I think there are better places to get this answer." Since there's a dedicated Physics exchange with users who solve this type of problem regularly, I think that's a valid perspective; though in this case I suspect there may be gamedev-specific best practices (I just don't know them).